# Copy string data with NULL character inside string to char array

Tags: c++, string, null-character

I am trying to copy one string to char array, string have multiple NULL character. My problem is when first NULL character encountered my program stops copying the string.

I have used two approaches. This is what I am so far.

```
#include<iostream>
#include<string.h>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
    std::string str = "Hello World.\0 How are you?\0";
    char resp[2000];
    int i = 0;
    memset(resp, 0, sizeof(resp));
    /* Approach 1*/
    while(i < str.length())
    {
            if(str.at(i) == '\0')
            str.replace(str.begin(), str.begin()+i, " ");
        resp[i] = str.at(i);
        i++;
    }
    /* Approach 2*/
    memcpy(resp, str.c_str(), 2000);
    cout << resp << endl;
    return 0;
}
```

This program should print `Hello World. How are you?`. Please help me to correct this.

Comment: If you print `str.length()`, is it 12 or 24(ish)? I think your initialization is wrong. You will need to insert the 0 in the middle manually.

Comment: @MatsPetersson... Thanks mat it is 12 only.

Comment: I believe `cout` should output string only to the first zero byte anyway, am I wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `std::copy`:

```
std::copy(str.begin(), str.end(), std::begin(resp));
```

followed by `std::replace`:

```
std::replace(std::begin(resp), std::begin(resp) + str.size(), '\0', ' ');
```

You may want to define your character array so that it is full of zeros at the start:

```
char resp[2000] = {};
```

Comment: stringtoarray.cpp:23: error: `begin' is not a member of `std'

Comment: @someone You must be compiling with a pre-C++11 compiler. You can use `&resp[0]` instead.

Comment: Of course, that won't help the fact that the `std::string` is only initialized with the C-style string up to the first zero. You can have a std::string with NUL-characters in it, but you can't get it from a C-style string (in the way the original code does, at least).

Answer (score 1):

You could also one-shot it with

```
std::transform(
  str.begin(), str.end(), resp, [](char c) { return c == '\0' ? ' ' : c; }
);
```

Of course as @Mats has mentioned your string doesn't have any null chars, strings can also be initialized as follows though:

```
char const cstr[] = "Hello World.\0 How are you?";
std::string str(cstr, sizeof cstr);
```

C++14 has a `std::string` literal operator

```
std::string str = "Hello World.\0 How are you?"s;
```

Comment: This includes the trailing null also; possibly `sizeof cstr - 1` was intended